# Double Polymorphic Association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, polymorphism

I have a join table and I would like both the belongs_to associations to be polymorphic. The relationship would look as follows:

[image: Double Polymorhpic]

The class structure would look as follows:

```
Class Tagable1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tag_group_1s, :through => :taggings
  has_many :tag_group_2s, :through => :taggings
  ...
end

Class TagGroup1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :taggable_1s, :through => :taggings
  has_many :taggable_2s, :through => :taggings
  ...
end

Class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :taggable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :tag, :polymorphic => true
end
```

There's obvious drawbacks to this approach, especially the heavy load on the Taggings table. What I'm trying to achieve is a flexible design which allows me to create new Taggables or TagGroups without creating new join tables. For instance, without the double polymorphic, Taggable1 would need a Taggable1Taggings table to join Taggable1 with the polymorphic TagGroups. Likewise, I would need Taggable2Taggings, Taggable3Taggings, Taggable4Taggings, etc etc.

I would love to be enlightened if there are drawbacks I'm not thinking of.

Comment: What are you tagging and what is a tag group? Difficult to offer advice if you don't share your actual design.

Comment: Taggables might be a Blog Post, Video, Food or Recipe. One TagGroup might be Food Groups for which the (self-referential) elements would be "Meats", another "Dairy", etc. Another TagGroup might be Dietary Restrictions for which the (self-referential) elements would be "Gluten Free", another "Peanut Free", etc.

Comment: And what is exactly your question? You want to know if your solution is a good choice?

Comment: Are there drawbacks to using a double polymorphic join?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's Rails 3 compatible, but you want the has_many_polymorphs gem:

https://github.com/fauna/has_many_polymorphs

this fork claims to be compatible with Rails 3:

https://github.com/jystewart/has_many_polymorphs

Comment: Thanks for this link! Their tagging system is along my lines. I just can't get myself to use it considering how outdated it is.

Answer (score 0):

seems the [acts-as-taggable-on gem](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) could make your life easier.

Comment: acts-as-taggable-on looks great but it doesn't seem to be able to tell you the inverse tag relationship. For instance, if I have tag 'blue', I can do User.tagged_with('blue') and Admin.tagged_with('blue') but I can't do Tag.find('blue').tagged_items for which it would give me all Users and all Admins.